Noetherian ring with the property that every irreducible is prime.
I have the following problem, i saw a solution but not understand the details.
Let $A$ be a noetherian ring. If every irreducible ideal is prime, prove that $A$ is a UFD.
We know the following fact about noetherian rings:
Every ideal of $A$ has a primary decomposition, and the primary ideals are irreducible.
So if $a \in A$, $(a)=p_1 \cap \cdots \cap p_n$, my question is:
Is it true that $p_1 \cap \cdots \cap p_n=p_1 \cdots p_n? $ or not necessarily?
Thanks.

Please specify exactly what you didn't understand about the solution, and where this solution is from.

My real question is, shouldn't the fact follow that every ideal can be factorized as an intersection of irreducibles? And that shouldn't imply that$ p_1 \cap \cdots \cap p_n=p_1 \cdots p_n$?
I found the the solution here https://planetmath.org/everypidisaufd, but they imitate the standard proof that every ideal in a noetheriang ring is intersection of irreducibles.

You have to prove that every ideal can be written as product of primes because $p_1 \cap \ldots p_n = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n$ is not necessarly true. In general it only holds that $ p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n \subseteq p_1 \cap \ldots \cap p_n$ and if you know that the primes are pairwise coprime, then the equality holds. But in general that can be a strict inclusion: consider the ring $k[x,y,z]$ with $k$ field. Let $p_1=(x,z)$ and $p_2=(y,z)$. Then $I=p_1 \cdot p_2=(xy,xz,yz,z^2)$ is strictly contained in $J=p_1 \cap p_2$ because, for example, $z \in J \setminus I$.
